# How to insert new condition in my function in R

Tags: r

Could you help me insert one more condition into my function below. So far I have two conditions: `(nrow(datas)<=2)`, the line created will use the `abline` function. If it's bigger, I'll use the `mod` function to create my line from there. It works fine for me. However I would like to create another condition, which is if `datas` presents 3 lines with equal values, the following condition will be performed:

```
 yz <- unique(datas$Numbers)
    lines(c(0,datas$Days), c(yz, datas$Numbers), lwd = 2)
    points(0, yz, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,yz+ .5,round(yz,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
```

Could you help me adjust this in my function?

```
f1 <- function(dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  

  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])-2):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,45), ylim= c(0,30),
       xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))
  
  m<-df1 %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR1"), mean))
  
  m<-subset(m, Week == df1$Week[match(ymd(dmda), ymd(df1$date2))] & Category == CategoryChosse)$DR1
  
  if (nrow(datas)<=2){
    
    abline(h=m,lwd=2) 
    points(0, m, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,m+ .5, round(m,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")}
    
  else{
    mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
    new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
    new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
    lines(new.data$Days,predict(mod,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
    coef<-coef(mod)[2]
    points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
    text(.99,coef + 1,max(0, round(coef,1)), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
    
  }
}
```

**Variable `datas`**

```
<-datas
  Category Days Numbers
  <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 ABC       42       2
2 ABC       43       2
3 ABC       44       2
```

It didn't work for this one.

```
<-datas
  Category Days Numbers
  <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 ABC       41       10.0
1 ABC       42       10.0
2 ABC       43       10.0
3 ABC       44       10.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want an `else if`:

```
...

if (nrow(datas)<=2){
  
  abline(h=m,lwd=2) 
  points(0, m, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
  text(.1,m+ .5, round(m,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  
  }else if(any(table(datas$Numbers) >= 3)){
    yz <- unique(datas$Numbers)
    lines(c(0,datas$Days), c(yz, datas$Numbers), lwd = 2)
    points(0, yz, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,yz+ .5,round(yz,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  
  }else{
    mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
    new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
    new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
    lines(new.data$Days,predict(mod,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
    coef<-coef(mod)[2]
    points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
    text(.99,coef + 1,max(0, round(coef,1)), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  }
}
```

Edit:

```
> datas <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1), b = c(2,2,2))
> datas
  a b
1 1 2
2 1 2
3 1 2
# Test if each row is a duplicate
> duplicated(datas)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> sum(TRUE)
[1] 1
> sum(duplicated(datas)) >= 2
[1] TRUE

# But beware, it is counting all duplicates, not
# just for a specific duplicate existing three times.
# For example:

> datas <-data.frame(a = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), b = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5))
> datas
  a b
1 3 3
2 3 3
3 4 4
4 4 4
5 5 5
6 5 5
> duplicated(datas)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> sum(duplicated(datas))
[1] 3

# This is more straightforward if you are
# just interested in duplicates in one column:

# This is the frequency of each value in datas$b
> table(datas$b)
3 4 5 
2 2 2 
# Which frequencies greater than or equal to 3?
> table(datas$b) >= 3
3     4     5 
FALSE FALSE FALSE
# Are ANY frequencies greater than or equal to 3?
> any(table(datas$b)>=3)
[1] FALSE
# You could try this:
# }else if(any(table(datas$Numbers) >= 3)){...new function...}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! What does it mean `(sum(duplicated(datas)) >= 2`

Comment: You're welcome! Take a look at the edit in my answer to see how that chunk behaves. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Skaqqs, Unfortunately it didn't work out. I inserted the result in my `datas` variable in the question so you can see what it looks like. It's actually just the colunmn `Numbers` that have equal values. So, when that happens, that is, having three equal numbers, that condition is executed.

Comment: I think I get what you want to do now. You want to execute the new function when `datas$Numbers` has 3 or more identical values?

Comment: Great, I updated the edit of my answer

Comment: Skaqqs, in the first case it worked, however when I went to generate it for the second table I inserted above, it didn't work. In this second case he would have to use the `mod` function, but if I leave the `end if` that you made it doesn't work. It only works if I don't have the `end if`. Do you know what it can be?

Comment: If you post example input data, I can try to troubleshoot. You can use `dput()` in R to generate a chunk, and copy and paste it in your question.

Comment: Skaqqs, Can I insert the example in this same question for you to see?

Comment: Yes, I'll see it there.

Comment: My brother asked a new question about this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532680/graph-is-not-generated-if-i-consider-the-else-if-condition please, can check?

Comment: I added a comment there.